# Quaternion - Angle computation using accelerometer and gyroscope

Tags: math, 3d, rotation, quaternions, euler-angles

I have been using a **6dof** LSM6DS0 IMU unit (with accelerometer and gyroscope). And I am trying to calculate the angle of rotation around all the three axes. I have tried may methods but not getting the results as expected.

**Methods tried:**

(i) Complementatry filter approach - I am able to get the angles using the formula provided in the link [Angle comutation method](http://www.pieter-jan.com/node/11).

But the problem is that angles are not at all consistent and drifts a lot. Moreover when the IMU is rotated around one axis, angles calculated over other axis are wobbling too much.

(ii) Quaternion based angle calculation : There were plenty of resources claiming the angles are calcluated very well using quaternion approach but none had a  clear explanation. I have used [this method](http://www.x-io.co.uk/open-source-imu-and-ahrs-algorithms/) in order to update the quaternion for every values taken from the IMU unit. But the link dint explain how to calculate the angles from quaternion.

I have used **glm math** library inorder to convert the quaternion to euler angles and also have tried the formula specified in [wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles). With this method since in pitch calculation asin returns only -90 to +90 degrees I am not able to rotate the object in 3D as the one they have been doing in the mentioned link.

Does anyone have tried the quaternion to angle conversion before?? I need to calculate the angles around all the three axis in the range 0 to 360 degrees or -180 to +180 degrees.

Any help could be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Guess to use existing solutions for sensor fusion. like http://www.x-io.co.uk/open-source-imu-and-ahrs-algorithms/

Comment: Yes this is the same link I have posted too in Quaternion based angle calculation. The thing is they dint expose how they are calculating the angles from quaternion.

Comment: If you need to convert quaternion to euler angels , than use this library 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles

And code from article "Euler angle conversion" by Ken Shoemake in "graphic gems 4" 
http://www.realtimerendering.com/resources/GraphicsGems/

Answer (score 1):

http://davidegironi.blogspot.com.ar/2013/02/avr-atmega-mpu6050-gyroscope-and.html#.VzjDKfnhCUk

```
  Sq = [q0, q1, q2, q3]
  //sensor quaternion can be translated to aerospace sequence of yaw/pitch/roll angles
  yaw = atan2(2*q1*q2 - 2*q0*q3, 2*(q0^2) + 2*(q1^2) - 1)
  pitch = -asin(2*q1*q3 + 2*q0*q2)
  roll = atan2(2*q2*q3 - 2*q0*q1, 2*(q0^2) + 2*(q3^2) - 1)
```